# Fedora29においてdnf installでsudoの入力をしなくてもいいようにしたい

Tags: sudo, fedora

最近Fedoraをインストールしてみたのですがsudoと打たなくても自動的にdnf update,dnf installするときにsudoを付加したいです。
他にもLinux mintを使っているのですがMintのaptでは標準でできたのでいちいちsudoを入力するのが面倒で仕方ありません。

```
$ apt install hoge
[sudo] xxxx のパスワード:
パッケージリストを読み込んでいます... 完了
依存関係ツリーを作成しています               
状態情報を読み取っています... 完了
・・・
```

こんな感じにしたいです。
一応、suでrootになるのやパスワードの入力をしなくていいようにしたいわけではありません。
お手数おかけしますがよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「コマンドの`sudo`を毎回入力するのが面倒なだけで、sudo実行時のパスワード入力は問題としない」であれば、以下のような`alias`を設定すればよさそうです。

```
$ alias dnf='sudo dnf'
```

ログイン時に反映されるようにするには、`.bashrc`辺りに記述してください。